# What is the value of $1^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

What is the value of $1^i$? $\,$

Answer (score 75, accepted):

First, a concrete example of things that can happen with complex exponentiation if you aren't careful: $1 = e^{2\pi i}$, so we can naively try to compute $1^i = (e^{2\pi i})^i = e^{(2\pi i)i} = e^{-2\pi}$.

The formal moral of that example is that the value of $1^i$ depends on the branch of the complex logarithm that you use to compute the power. You may already know that $1=e^{0+2ki\pi}$ for every integer $k$, so there are many possible choices for $\log(1)$.

The textbook definition of complex exponentiation states that $1^i = e^{\log(1)i}$ where "log" is a branch of the complex logarithm.

Now $e^{(2ki\pi)i} = e^{-2k\pi}$. If you take $k = 0$, which corresponds to using the principal branch of the logarithm, you get an answer of $1^i = e^0 = 1$. If you take $k = 2$ as in the example above, using the fact that $1=e^{2\pi i}$, you get $1^i = e^{-2\pi}$. There are infinitely many possible values for $1^i$, corresponding to different branches of the complex logarithm.

The confusing point here is that the formula $1^x = 1$ is not part of the definition of complex exponentiation, although it is an immediate consequence of the definition of natural number exponentiation.

A second point that can be confusing is that the function $e^z$ used above is really the complex exponential function $\exp(z)$, which is defined by a power series. Otherwise, the definition of complex exponentiation would be circular.

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake about the fact that the branches *do* matter.  I deleted my response since it a) it was wrong and b) it's now unneccesary in light of your answer.  You may wish you modify your paragraph "As another response has pointed out....", though.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No problem, I removed that phrase.

Comment: I think this solution is wrong -- the function $a^b$ is single-valued and unambiguously defined whenever $a$ is real and positive. I posted a solution with more detail.

Comment: There's no exception in the definition of complex exponentiation for the case when the base is positive and real, or for the case when the base is 1. For example, it's quite common in complex analysis to distinguish between the single-valued function $\exp(z)$ and the multiple-valued function $e^z=\exp(z\log(e))$. It is true that you can make the exponential single-valued by picking a particular branch of the logarithm, but any such choice is somewhat arbitrary. The complex exponential itself is inherently multivalued, like the complex logarithm.

Comment: Well then why didn't Euler say "$e^{i\pi} = -1$, and other values as well"? I think the onus is on you to prove that "it's quite common in complex analysis" to do this. I just did another google search, and the first two results for complex analysis notes defined the complex exponential either via power series, or via DeMoivre.

Comment: @LL: I think you may be confusing the multivalued complex function $\exp(z\log(e))$ with the single-valued complex function $\exp(z)$. Both of these functions, unfortunately, can be denoted $e^z$, and the only term I know to refer to either one is "exponential function". In my post of 11:24 I am referring to the multivalued one. Many texts in complex analysis mention this notational issue, usually so that the authors can say that $e^z$ will be used to refer to $\exp(z)$ in their book. But the original question is not about the function $\exp(z)$, it is about $\exp(i\log(1))$.

Comment: Actually, the original question is about $1^i$. You're the one that made it about $\exp(i\log(1))$ and then claimed that you'd have to consider alternate branches of the log function. Not a single source I've found defines $a^b$ in this manner when $a$ is real and positive. If your definition is so common, then please refer me to a textbook that explains this so I don't have to take your word for it.

Comment: The first example on Google books that I found by searching is "A first course in complex analysis with applications" by Dennis G. Zill and Patrick Shanahan, starting on p. 174 (section "Complex powers'). Now, I cannot vouch for that source completely. However, *every* textbook I have seen in complex analysis that defines the complex function $z^\alpha$ defines it as $\exp(\alpha\log(z))$; that is just the first book I found with a search. You can find several more on Google books. More advanced books in complex analysis seem not to bother with the function $z^\alpha$ at all.

Comment: that's just it -- $z$ is not complex. It's a positive real number. So this definition does not apply. As far as I'm concerned, $a^b$ only makes sense in two cases: 1) $a$ is real and positive and $b$ is complex, or 2) $a$ is complex and $b$ is an integer.

I guess if you want to define it differently and make it multivalued, nobody is going to stop you... I just don't think there is any reason for it. The reason log(z) is multivalued is because exp(z) is periodic, and we define $y = \log(z)$ such that $\exp(y) = z$. Making $a^b$ multivalued for real positive $a$ makes no sense.

Comment: Every real number is (identified with) a complex number. One could equally well point out that $i$ is not a real number, and so the usual definitions of real-valued exponentiation in elementary calculus cannot handle $1^i$ because they are only defined for real inputs. The complex exponential function $z^\alpha$ is defined for all nonzero complex $z$, even those identified with real numbers. There is no other familiar definition that applies to the power $1^i$. If you had a definition of $z^\alpha$ that distinguishes real and complex inputs, how would you define a Riemann surface for it?

Comment: I think we can both agree on one thing -- there should be two definitions. $3^2$ should not be multivalued, but $(-1+i)^{1+i}$ needs to be because its ambiguous. We disagree on where to draw the line. I argue that $1^i$ can be nonambiguously single-valued, since it requires taking the log of a positive real number. You argue that if either of the arguments is complex, we should use the alternate definition in terms of log and allow multiple branches. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree here -- it is a semantic issue and not a mathematical one.

Comment: @LL: I do not agree with your last comment. I do not really see any reason to make $(-1+i)^{1+i}$ multivalued – it seems to me that useful computations are much easier when you pick one branch of $\ln$ and stick to it, making $a^b$ denote exactly one complex number for complex numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a \neq 0$ (or $b > 0$ for $a=0$). There's enough literature out there doing exactly that, try “Can Your Computer do Complex Analysis?” by Aslaksen or Knuth et al.'s papers on the Lambert W function.

Comment: @LL: I agree with that.

Comment: Please provide an answer by computing a value for $1^i$ for some branch

Comment: @Nikos M.: The fourth paragraph has the calculation for two different branches.

Comment: @Carl Mummert , yes i see, still the objection of a comment in the other answer holds regarding the ambiguity. How about $0^i$, how should this be interpreted or calculated?

Comment: @Nikos M.: If we follow the definitions that are typically employed in complex analysis, $0^i$ is undefined, because there is no branch of the logarithm that includes $0$. Indeed, if we are talking about the *complex* power function $a^z$, it is undefined for $a = 0$ regardless of $z$. Even $0^2$ is undefined when it refers to the complex power function.

Comment: @Carl, got it thanks

Comment: @Carl, by the same token is this $1^i/1^i$ undefined like $\infty/\infty$ ?

Comment: @Carl, there are other cases in math, where typcal definitions have been used in order to provide a 'closure' or simplify and avoid ambiguities, eg 0! = 1 (by definition/convention), the definiton for n! does not account for n=0, analytical continuation (since we are on complex analysis), is exactly (or at least very close to) that also. Thank you up to now for providing feedback

Comment: Isn't this a similar issue we face when we raise an equation into a power? Basically we have the equation: $1^i = x$. If we assume power is a single valued function, then $x = 1$. On the other hand if you raise both sides of the equation to the power of $-i$, you would have the equation $1 = x^{-i}$ which has infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 3):

$1^{i} = e^{\log(1) i} = e^{0}=1$

Comment: this sounds good to me too, since 1 is real why isnt $\log(1)$ zero? see also previous comment in other answer

Answer (score 0):

it's 1. 1 to the power of anything is 1.

**Edit:** I'll elaborate. In defining $a^b$, we know intuitively what to do in certain cases. When $a$ is a positive integer and $b$ is an integer, for example. This definition is easily extended to when $a$ is real and positive, and $b$ is a real number. In the case where $a$ is negative, or complex, we run into trouble... one way to get around this is to define the power in terms of the logarithm, as $a^b = e^{b \log a}$. Then, we have the issue that the logarithm is multivalued, so we could get different answers depending on which branch we choose. This is the approach discussed in Carl's solution.

I do not believe this proposed method applies for the case where $a$ is positive and real, which is the relevant case being discussed. In the case where $a$ is positive and real, $a^b$ is unambiguously defined as $a^b = e^{b \ln a}$, where $\ln a$ is the unique real number $x$ satisfying $e^x = a$. This definition works even in the case where $b$ is complex. So we can apply this to the original problem: $1^i = e^{i\log(1)} = e^0 = 1$ (Myke, you got my +1!). In fact, $1^z = 1$ for any complex $z$. This viewpoint is shared by [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Power.html), [WolframAlpha](http://tinyurl.com/25xjy9z), and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28mathematics%29), for what that's worth.

I guess at some level, it's a question of semantics and preference. Why not use multiple branches and all that jazz for the case where $a>0$? Because (and this is my opinion), it's unnecessary, and doesn't fit with existing definitions. The exponential function $e^z$ is well-defined via a power series and I think everyone would agree that it is single-valued, even when $z$ is complex. It makes no sense to me that $a^z$ should be any different when $a$ is real and positive.

Comment: This is only *part* of the truth. It is also true that $1^i=e^{-2\pi}$... In particular, your claim «1 to the power of anything is 1» is false—without extra context, at least.

Comment: I made a massive edit.

Comment: +1. It is true that there are multiple functions which provide inverses for restrictions of the exponential function; but it is not true that "$1^i=1$ and also $1^i=\mathrm e^{-2\pi}$". At best, this is shorthand for the position that the absence of a 'distinguished' inverse function for $\exp(x)$ entails that there is no meaningful convention for interpreting the expression "$1^x$". But then one should also view the expressions $\ln(1)$ and $\sqrt 2$ with equal suspicion. --- In practice, we identify a distinguished inverse by convention; $1^i = 1$ for the same reason that $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: Of course the answer will depend on the definition of $1^i$. However, the convention of using the principal branch of the logarithm is not nearly as well established as using the positive square root for $\sqrt{2}$. We usually point it out explicitly when we use the principal branch when doing a computation with complex logarithms. Also, it's a common exercise in complex analysis texts to compute all the possible values of $2^i$ or $i^i$. The case of $1^i$ is completely parallel to those from the viewpoint of the definition of complex exponentiation.

Comment: Sure, its a standard exercise to compute sets $\exp(i\cdot exp^{−1}(2))$ and $\exp(i\cdot \exp^{-1}(i))$, involving pre-images of 2 and i under the exponential function. But to pretend that one should routinely consider 'logarithm' functions per se, which aren't monotone functions on the reals --- so that consequently expressions such as $x \mapsto 2^x$ also may not be monotone functions on the reals --- seems quite fanciful. There is more than one way to choose such a 'logarithm' function on ℂ, sure; but for each one, the corresponding definition of $1^x$ yields the same constant function.

Comment: @Niel de Beaudrap: Complex analysis book routinely consider arbitrary branches of the logarithm. I disagree with your last sentence, even when $x$ is real. If we take a branch of the logarithm where $\log(1) = 2\pi i$ then $1^{1/2} = \exp(\pi i) = -1$ which is not equal to $1^1 = \exp(2\pi i) = 1$. Complex exponentiation is not the same function as real exponentiation; they only agree for appropriate branches of the logarithm, and then that agreement has to be proved, it is not a definition. Complex exponentiation is only ever well-defined relative to a choice of a branch of the logarithm.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: Well, you've violated the (perhaps not clearly articulated) precondition of that sentence: selecting a log function which is monotone on the reals --- in particular, *real* on the reals. (As you show, violating this allowed $\sqrt 1$ to be negative, violating a convention which you seem to suggest as being independent, or "better established".) --- I doubt that this debate is resolvable; but I'm interested in notation with utility, which requires consistency with other utilitarian choices. If I wanted more branches, I'd refer to $\exp^{-1}$, which is what is really meant anyway.

Comment: @Carl: “Complex exponentiation is only ever well-defined relative to a choice of a branch of the logarithm.” – Absolutely true. So we should pick a branch (there is a common way of doing that, so if that choice does what we need, we should), then we can call the logarithm and $(a,b) \mapsto a^b$ a “function” again and continue with more interesting questions.

Comment: This sounds good to me. Another of these paradoxes (classical) maths are full of

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, $e^{-2\pi}$ is also 1

Comment: @NikosM., no it is not!

Comment: Dont you miss (and i also) and $i$ in the exponent? So this should be $e^{-2i\pi}$ which is 1?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, sorry got confused. Why since log(1) has real argument, is not always zero?

Comment: @Carl Mummert, the example you provided with $1^1/2$ equals -1, is very wrong and i will explain why. First since someone can just interpret it as *complex operation* or *real operation* equally, would result in 2 different outcomes, with exactly the same notation and values. This is surely **not** what you would like to call mathematical clarity?

Comment: @Nikos M.: there is nothing that we can do about the fact that the notation $1^{1/2}$ is ambiguous.

Comment: @Carl will have to disagree, yes we can and in fact other answers (although yours is good) have answered this part also

Comment: @Carl assuming one to any power to be always one, would it result in some other part of the existing mathematics become scrambled?

Comment: Mathworld does indeed agree with you.