# Euler's number in exponential form of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, education

Why in the exponential form of complex numbers is used the Euler's number?

$$z=\rho \space e^{j\phi} $$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What's a "Neper number"? Do you mean $\phi$?

Comment: Hi @Omnomnomnom, I mean $e$. In Italy we call it Neper's number instead of Euler's number.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/understanding-imaginary-exponents) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39913/complex-exponents).  There are also some videos that might help, such as [this (Kahn academy)](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-home/series-calc/maclaurin-taylor-calc/v/euler-s-formula-and-euler-s-identity) and [this one (3Blue1Brown)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_0yfvm0UoU)

Comment: The tag "eulers-constant" is not for $e$, it is for $\gamma$