# A complex number in the power of another complex number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/a-complex-number-to-the-power-of-another-complex-number) question, and found a formula:
$$=\cos \left( d\log |a+bi|+c\arctan \frac{d}{c}\right)+i\sin \left( d\log |a+bi|+c\arctan \frac{d}{c}\right).$$
Which I later translated to Microsoft Math format:
cos(d*log(Abs(a+bi))+c*arctan(d/c))+sin(d*log(Abs(a+bi))+c*arctan(d/c))*i
And - that formula gives wrong results.
While the result is `-0.507 - 0.861i` (for that formula, setting `a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4`)
Doing `(a + bi)^(c + di)` gives me `0.129+0.033i`
Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong ? (I am trying to write a program which does this.)

Comment: Taking the power of a complex number by a complex number isn't uniquely defined, as is already explained in the question you linked to.

Comment: So how exactly does Microsoft Math calculate it ?

Comment: Who knows? I don't even know what that is.

Comment: The veracity of a formula producing a complex number of modulus 1 for *every* (a+bi)^(c+di), as yours seems to be doing, is highly dubious. Another, similar, remark is that your formula gives 1 for every (a,b,c,d) such that d=0. Hmmm...

Comment: That wasn't my formula but Americo Tavareses...

Comment: No it is not: you forgot the $e^{c\log∣a+bi∣−d\arctan(d/c)}$ part.

Comment: But there are some (other unrelated) problems with Americo's formula.

Comment: @Didier Piau: I corrected the formula in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/a-complex-number-to-the-power-of-another-complex-number/9793#9793) as per Ross Milikan's comment.

Comment: Correction: $$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( a+bi\right) ^{c+di} &=&e^{(c+di)\left( \log \left\vert
a+bi\right\vert +i\arctan \frac{b}{a}\right) } \\
&=&e^{c\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert -d\arctan \frac{b}{a}}e^{i\left( d\ln
\left\vert a+ib\right\vert +c\arctan \frac{b}{a}\right) } \\
&=&e^{c\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert -d\arctan \frac{b}{a}}\left( \cos
\left( d\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert +c\arctan \frac{b}{a}\right) +i\sin
\left( d\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert +c\arctan \frac{b}{a}\right) \right) 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: It doesn't yield the same result Mathematica 8 does. Playing around with Expand gave me this formula: ((a + bI)^2)^((c + dI)/2) Cos[(c + dI) Arg[a + bI]] + 
 I ((a + bI)^2)^((c + dI)/2) Sin[(c + dI) Arg[a + bI]]

Comment: Wait - that doesn't even helps me. God damn it

Comment: And I corrected the formula once more: $$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( a+bi\right) ^{c+di} &=&e^{(c+di)\text{ Log }(a+bi)} \\
&=&e^{(c+di)\left( \ln |a+bi|+i\arg (a+bi)\right) } \\
&=&e^{c\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert -d\arg \left( a+ib\right) +i\left(
c\arg \left( a+ib\right) +d\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert \right) } \\
&=&e^{c\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert -d\arg(a+bi)}\times  \\
&&\times \left( \cos \left( c\arg \left( a+ib\right) +d\ln \left\vert
a+ib\right\vert \right) +i\sin \left( c\arg \left( a+ib\right) +d\ln
\left\vert a+ib\right\vert \right) \right). 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: I don't see what this adds to the linked question (and many others linked there) -- voting to close as too localized.

Comment: I am sorry for the errors in my answer. I revised it. Would you mind using the revised formula?  I detailed the computation for your case $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4$ and for $a=-1,b=2,c=3,d=4$ and both results agree with the computations performed in Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: In the present case $\arctan 2/1=\arg(1+2i)$ (the principle argument of $(1+2i)$. However, since in general it may be different, e.g. $\arg(-1+2i)=\arctan(-2)+\pi=-\arctan 2+\pi$, I revised my answers and used only $\arg(a+bi)$.

Comment: @Didier Piau: I corrected the formula once more. Now it should be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I corrected [the answer you cite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/a-complex-number-to-the-power-of-another-complex-number/9793#9793). Instead of the $\arctan$ function it should be the $\arg$ function. These two functions are not always equal. The $\arg$ function is used in the principal logarithm of $z=x+iy$, which is the complex number

$$w=\text{Log }z=\log |z|+i\arg z$$

so that $e^w=z$, where $\arg z$ (the principal argument of $z$) is the real number in $-\pi\lt \arg z\le \pi$, with $x=|z|\cos (\arg z)$ and $y=|z|\sin (\arg z)$.

The formula now reads as follows:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( a+bi\right) ^{c+di} &=&e^{(c+di)\text{ Log }(a+bi)} \\
&=&e^{(c+di)\left( \ln |a+bi|+i\arg (a+bi)\right) } \\
&=&e^{c\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert -d\arg \left( a+ib\right) +i\left(
c\arg \left( a+ib\right) +d\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert \right) } \\
&=&e^{c\ln \left\vert a+ib\right\vert -d\arg(a+bi)}\times  \\
&&\times \left( \cos \left( c\arg \left( a+ib\right) +d\ln \left\vert
a+ib\right\vert \right) +i\sin \left( c\arg \left( a+ib\right) +d\ln
\left\vert a+ib\right\vert \right) \right). 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

For $a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4$, we have (numeric computations in SWP)

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( 1+2i\right) ^{3+4i} &=&e^{(3+4i)\text{ Log }(1+2i)} \\
&=&e^{(3+4i)\left( \log |1+2i|+i\arg (1+2i)\right) } \\
&=&e^{3\ln \left\vert 1+2i\right\vert -4\arg \left( 1+2i\right) +i\left(
3\arg \left( 1+2i\right) +4\ln \left\vert 1+2i\right\vert \right) } \\
&=&e^{3\ln \left\vert 1+2i\right\vert -4\arg \left( 1+2i\right) }\times  \\
&&\times \left( \cos \left( 3\arg \left( 1+2i\right) +4\ln \left\vert
1+2i\right\vert \right) +i\sin \left( 3\arg \left( 1+2i\right) +4\ln
\left\vert 1+2i\right\vert \right) \right)  \\
&\approx &0.13340\left( \cos \left( 6.5403\right) +i\sin \left(
6.5403\right) \right)  \\
&\approx &0.12901+3.3924\times 10^{-2}i,
\end{eqnarray*}$$

which agrees with the [computation in Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2b2i%29%5E%283%2b4i%29) for $(1+2i)^{3+4i}.$

And for instance, if $a=-1,b=2,c=3,d=4,$ then

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\left( -1+2i\right) ^{3+4i} &=&e^{(3+4i)\text{ Log }(-1+2i)} \\
&=&e^{(3+4i)\left( \log |-1+2i|+i\arg (-1+2i)\right) } \\
&=&e^{3\ln \left\vert -1+2i\right\vert -4\arg \left( -1+2i\right) +i\left(
3\arg \left( -1+2i\right) +4\ln \left\vert -1+2i\right\vert \right) } \\
&=&e^{3\ln \left\vert -1+2i\right\vert -4\arg \left( -1+2i\right) }\times  \\
&&\times \left( \cos \left( 3\arg \left( -1+2i\right) +4\ln \left\vert
-1+2i\right\vert \right) +i\sin \left( 3\arg \left( -1+2i\right) +4\ln
\left\vert -1+2i\right\vert \right) \right)  \\
&\approx &3.267\,9\times 10^{-3}\left( \cos \left( 9.3222\right) +i\sin
\left( 9.3222\right) \right)  \\
&\approx &3.\,250\,7\times 10^{-3}+3.346\times 10^{-4}i.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

In Wolfram Alpha [we get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%2b2i%29%5E%283%2b4i%29) $(-1+2i)^{3+4i}\approx -0.003250688+0.000334598i$

Comment: @Quantic Programming: You are welcome! Sorry for the errors in my old answer!

Answer (score 3):

The formula you cite is in Américo Tavares' response to the question.  I believe the argument of the $\arctan$ should be $\frac{b}{a}$.  When I plug it into Wolfram Alpha with your constants, I get about $0.9671+0.2543i.$  It is the exponential of only the imaginary part, so you need to multiply it by the exponential of the real part:  $e^{c\log |a+bi|-d\arctan \frac{b}{a}}\approx 0.1333$ if you expect $(1+2i)^{(3+4i)}$ and it comes out.

Comment: I corrected the formula in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9776/a-complex-number-to-the-power-of-another-complex-number/9793#9793) as per your comment.

Comment: Could you please check sign in $−0.2543i$? (I got $0.2543i$)

Comment: @Américo Tavares:  I agree.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Just an information. In the present case $\arctan 2/1=\arg(1+2i)$ (the principle argument of $(1+2i)$. However, since in general it may be different, e.g. $\arg(-1+2i)=\arctan(-2)+\pi=-\arctan 2+\pi$, I revised my answers and used only $\arg(a+bi)$.