# How would I calculate the arctan of a complex number and is the formula below correct? Ex: arctan(7i/5)

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am working on debugging a program I made that would raise a complex number to a complex power Ex: (a+bi)^(c+di). I'm running into issues when trying to calculate the inverse tangent of (di/c) for the calculation of atan(d/c) in my final equation of Z = e^((a+bi)(ln(sqrt(c^2 + d^2) + i(atan(d/c))). Is this formula the correct way to go about finding a complex number to a complex power, and how would I calculate the atan of d/c by hand? Thank you!

Comment: Well, ordinarily, when you want to calculate $z^w$, you need only a good hold on $\log(z)$. Are you sure you’re doing the right thing?

Comment: @Lubin I'm fairly sure I am, I found the formula I'm using in a seperate thread. This could be incorrect however. I can't seem to find a reliable source for ways to do this type of calculation anywhere https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3816175

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:

Use the fact that
$$\arctan z=-i\operatorname{artanh} iz$$
Letting $z=ix$, we find that
$$\arctan ix=i\operatorname{artanh} x$$
where
$\operatorname{artanh} x$ is the inverse hyperbolic tangent function.