# What are the values of $(-1)^{2i}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the value of $1^i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/what-is-the-value-of-1i)

I read that 
$$
(-1)^{2i}=\exp(2i\log -1)=\exp(-2\pi-4\pi k)
$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. How does the second equality follow?

I calculate $\cos(2i\log(-1))=1$ and $\sin(2i\log(-1))=0$, but I don't see how a $-2\pi-4\pi k$ appears like this.

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logarithm can be considered a [multi-valued function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_function). Backstory: since $\displaystyle e^{\pi i}+1=0$, we may conclude that $\displaystyle e^{2\pi i}=1$ and so $\displaystyle e^{\pi i+2k\pi i}=-1$ for any integer $k$. So which of these $\pi i+2k\pi i$ is the value of $\log(-1)$ then? Generally a particular [branch cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) is chosen so that the logarithm only obtains one of these values, but clearly here the formula is valid for integers $k$, only for different choices of branches with each $k$, and this what might be intended in the purported equality.