# Why does $1^{-i}$ equal 1?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

At one point, I found an equation that works with complex logarithms, but I lost the book that contains the equation. If I feed this to Wolfram|Alpha, it states that $1^{-i}$ is equal to 1. Why is $1^{-i} = 1$?

Comment: because $a^z = \exp(z\log a) $ for any real number $a$?

Comment: Note that we have to be careful with our definition of complex exponentiation.  I could claim with equal consistency that
$$
1^{-i} = (e^{2 \pi i})^{-i} = e^{2 \pi}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Isn't it somewhat standard to take the $(-\pi,\pi]$ branch of the complex logarithm?

Comment: @user2345215 yes; however, it's occasionally useful to switch branches though (for example, taking $[0,2 \pi)$), and that choice often depends on the context.

Comment: Well $1^z$ is a multi valued function, right?

Comment: As explained at this question, there are infinitely many different values of $1^{-i}$, depending on which branch of the complex logarithm you take. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/what-is-the-value-of-1i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $a^b = e^{b \log a}$, we have

$$1^{-i} = e^{-i \log 1} = e^{-i \cdot 2k\pi i} = e^{2k\pi}$$

Note that in the complex numbers $\log^\mathbb C z = \log^\mathbb R |z| + (2k \pi + \arg z)i$, so there are infinite choices for its value.

One of the values that $1^{-i}$ takes is $1$, but it is not always $1$.
If we set $k = 0$, the resulting number it's called principal value (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value), and  that is what wolfram reports.

With $k=0$ you get $e^0 = 1$

Comment: This leaves out the key fact that there are many different choice for $\log(1)$ in the complex numbers.

Comment: @CarlMummert You are correct. It should be fixed now

Comment: There is a typo in the revision. $e^{-i\log i} = e^{-i\cdot 2k\pi i} = e^{2k\pi}$. This will given different values depending on the value of $k$; it's not always $1$. But it is $1$ when $k =0$; this corresponds to the principal value.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thanks! I was superficial :) It is okay now?

Comment: It seems OK, except the last non-equality is sometimes an equality, depending on what $k$ is.

Answer (score 0):

Given any $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$ we define $a^b=e^{b\ \log\ (a)}$. Thus in this case $1^{-i}$ = $e^{-i\log (1)}$ = $1$.

Comment: This leaves out the key fact that there are many different choice for $\log(1)$ in the complex numbers.

Comment: @CarlMummert that's true; i assumed that we are talking about the principal value, as the question which has been asked is that why is $1^{-i}=1$, not that what are the possible values for $1^{-i}$.

Comment: That is the question, but the answer is "in general, it's not". It is certainly true that the principal value of $1^{-i}$ is $1$, of course.

Comment: @CarlMummert right!!