# If $z=i^{2i}$ then $|z| =?$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am given a complex number $z=i^{2i}$ so what would be $|z|$?
Firstly I took $\log$

$$
\log(z)=2i\log i\\
$$
thus
$$
\log(z)=2i\log(e^{-π/2}) = -i\pi;
$$
then inverting the log
$$
z=e^{ -i\pi}
$$
implying
$$ |z| =1.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: $|z|=1$ and follows directly... if you insert absolute value on both sides

Comment: how do you prove if $z=e^{-i\pi}$ then $|z|=1$?

Comment: Oops it looks like my Euler conversion is wrong

Comment: @JonMarkPerry $z=\cos (-\pi) -\sin(-\pi) $ and the result follows that $|z|=1$.

Comment: $i=e^{-i\pi/2}$? (square it you get $-1$).

Comment: Yes but is result $z=e^-π$ correct ? Is this method valid?

Comment: @Tesla: the most reliable way to figure out these kinds of problems is to go back to the definition $z^w = \exp(w\log(z))$ and work from there, as in several answers below.

Answer (score 5):

All of the values of $i^{2i}$ are real. The possible values are
 $$i^{2i} = e^{2i\cdot\log i}=e^{2i\cdot(\frac{\pi}{2}i+2k\pi i)}
=e^{-\pi -4k\pi}=e^{-(4k+1)\pi}
$$
which are all positive, so they are all possible values of $|z|$.

Note that none of these is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Remember:

- By definition, $i^{2i} = \exp(2i \cdot \log(i))$.
- There are infinitely many different possible values of $\log(i)$. Because of the way $\exp(z)$ works, we have $e^{\pi i/2} = i$ and $e^{2\pi i n} = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So the values of $\log(i)$ are of the form $\pi i/2 + 2\pi i n = i\pi(1/2 +2n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

The combination of these facts (that complex powers are defined relative to a complex logarithm, and that the complex logarithm in general has more than one possible value) cause complex exponents to behave very differently from real ones (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/what-is-the-value-of-1i) for another example: $1^i$ is not always $1$).

In the case at hand, $i^{2i}$, we can choose any integer $n$ in the logarithm of $i$, obtaining
$$
i^{2i} = \exp(2i \cdot \pi i (1/2 + 2n)) = \exp(-2\pi(1/+2n)) = \exp((-1-4n)\pi)
$$

The exponent there is completely real, so the value of the exponential function will match the value of the real exponential function. You can see that there are infinitely many different possible values for $|i^{2i}|$, one for each value of $\log(i)$ (that is, one for each value of $n$).

Comment: I think you have a typo , it should be $e^{\pi i}=-1$.

Comment: @Tolaso: thanks for pointing that out; I have fixed it

Answer (score 2):

$i=e^{\frac12\pi i}$ so that $$i^{2i}=(e^{\frac12\pi i})^{2i}=e^{\frac12\pi i.2i}=e^{-\pi}$$

---

**edit**

This answer is not complete. See the comments of Carl. It only computes the so-called principle value. This by picking the usual logarithm. Be aware of the confusion that can arise here. I was a victim of that myself.

Comment: This is only part of the story; see the answer by MPW

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, I have seen that, and realize that it is indeed not the whole story. I am still wondering though where things go wrong in my answer.

Comment: The issue is that $i$ is also $e^{5\pi i/2}$, $e^{9\pi i /2}$, etc.   This answer finds the principal value by picking the "usual" logarithm.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thank you. Of course you mean $i$ here (not $1$). I will delete this answer within some minutes.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But it would not be bad to just leave a note that this computes the principal value - this is a common point of confusion (e.g. this very question)

Comment: @CarlMummert I solved it by means of this edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line is not correct, the property $\ln x^a=a\ln x$ is only valid for real numbers.  However it is true that $e^{\ln x^a}=e^{a\ln x}$. So, in the end, your answer is correct.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that $\ln x^a=a\ln x$ is also valid for complex numbers.

Comment: Actually it's not. Consider  the branch of $\ln$ for which $-\pi\le\text{arg }z<\pi$. $\ln (e^{3\pi i/4})^2=\ln(-i)=-\frac\pi 2$, but $2\ln e^{3\pi i/4}=\frac{3\pi i}2.$

Comment: @barakmanos No it does not. You have to take into account the branch of the log , since it is a multivalued function. But what does hold is:

$$\log z_1^{z_2} =z_2 \log z_1 + 2\pi i k , \;\; k \in \mathbb{Z}$$