# Does $1^i$ and $1^{\frac{0}{0}}$ also give $1$ again?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

This is the property of Real number $1$ that,

$1^n=1$ does this property only hold $\forall n \in \mathbb R$ or also $1^i=1$ and $1^{\frac{0}{0}}=1$

If it is; explain *how*?

I think that it should not give us $1$ again as we can't determine what is the square root of number $-1$ and similarly $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeterminate and so we can't proceed. May be I am wrong.

Comment: $1^i=\left(e^0\right)^i=e^{0\cdot i}=e^0=1$

Comment: As for $1^i$: this answer to a related question says it all: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/3674/101420

Comment: My question involves "what is $1^{\frac{0}{0}}$" and the question you are talking about doesn't.

Comment: But $\frac00$ isn't a number, so what would it even mean to talk about $1^\frac00$?

Comment: $\frac{0}{0}$ is indeterminate that is, we don't know that how many $0s$ are in $0$. Either one or many zeros or no zero. So I think that $1^{\frac{0}{0}}$ may or may not give us $1$. That confused me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$1^i$ is *defined* as $e^{i \ln 1}$

$\ln 1$, though, it's not our real logarithm, but it's the complex one; the point is that is a multi-valued function; to be more precise,

$$\ln z = \ln_\mathbb R |z| + (\arg z + 2k\pi)i$$

Where with $\ln_\mathbb R$ I mean the usual real logarithm.

So $\ln 1 = \ln_\mathbb R 1 + (2k\pi)i = 2k\pi i$

Hence $$1^i = e^{i \ln 1} = e^{-2k\pi}$$

So $1^i$ it's not really a number, it's more like a *set* of numbers; all the numbers in the form $e^{-2k\pi}$, $k \in \mathbb Z$.

The value $k=0$ is special and it's sometimes called the *principal value*; choosing this value for $k$ clearly results in $1^i = 1$, but it's important to understand that $1^i$ is not a well-defined number.

---

Note that, as @Jonathan Y. points out, a similar argument also holds for $1^{3/5}$. And if one thinks about it also for $\sqrt 1$, which is not a number but the set $\pm 1$.

The point is that we can define *without ambiguity* $\sqrt 1$ (take the positive value) and $1^{3/5}$ (there is only one real root).

One could naively think that the same could be done with $1^i$; just define in some way a *special value* and work with that. The point is that it can't be done; there is no way to specify a value without ambiguity and carry on all the usual algebra rules. So we're stuck with this multi valued definition if we are in the complex plane; if we are on the real line, instead, it's possible to define $a^{b/c}$ as a single value.

P.S. The principal value I referred to earlier it's sometimes useful but problems arise if you *define* the complex logarithm as it's principal value. Once you start studying complex analysis and (for example) the residue theorem it should be clear why :-)

Comment: A similar argument could be made for, e.g., $1^{3/5}$, which (I think) is even more startling.

Comment: @JonathanY. Thanks! I've edited the answer to include it :)

Answer (score 3):

$1^i$ is a multi-valued quantity $$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\implies e^{2n\pi i}=1\implies1^i=\color{RED}{e^{-2n\pi }}$$ for any integer $n.$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would like to know that the exponentiation by complex number does not work very well. The previous answers are correct, but what if you think like this?

$$1^i=(i^4)^i=(i^i)^4=((e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})^i)^4=(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}})^4=e^{-2\pi} \neq 1$$

Where is our God now? You have to be very careful when you do exponentiation with complex numbers.